HalpeCOCOAPI: '../common/maskApi.c': No such file or directory
Im trying to install Alphapose, but there is a problem when installing the dependency HalpeCOCOAPI. I cloned HalpeCOCOAPI(https://github.com/HaoyiZhu/HalpeCOCOAPI) individually and tried to install it following the instructions in the setup.py. I think the problem arises from the path to maskApi.c, a error about VisualStudio also appears after, but i don't know if it is corelated or not.
Setup.py file
from setuptools import setup, Extension
import numpy as np

#To compile and install locally run "python setup.py build_ext --inplace"
#To install library to Python site-packages run "python setup.py build_ext install"

ext_modules = [
    Extension(
        'halpecocotools._mask',
        sources=['common/maskApi.c', 'halpecocotools/_mask.pyx'],
        include_dirs = [np.get_include(), 'common'],
        extra_compile_args=[],
    )
]

setup(
    name='halpecocotools',
    packages = ['halpecocotools'],
    package_dir = {'halpecocotools': 'halpecocotools'},
    install_requires=[
        'setuptools>=18.0',
        'cython>=0.27.3',
        'matplotlib>=2.1.0',
    ],
    version='0.0.0',
    description="COCO API for Halpe-Fullbody dataset",
    url="https://github.com/HaoyiZhu/HalpeCOCOAPI",
    ext_modules= ext_modules
)

Error
PS C:\Users\USER\Desktop\ALPHA\HalpeCOCOAPI-master\PythonAPI> python3.7 setup.py build_ext --inplace
running build_ext
building 'halpecocotools._mask' extension
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\numpy\core\include -Icommon "-IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include" "-IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" /Tchalpecocotools/_mask.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\halpecocotools/_mask.obj
_mask.c
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
halpecocotools/_mask.c(6742): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'siz', possible loss of data
halpecocotools/_mask.c(7259): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'npy_intp' to 'siz', possible loss of data
halpecocotools/_mask.c(7259): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'npy_intp' to 'siz', possible loss of data
halpecocotools/_mask.c(7259): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'npy_intp' to 'siz', possible loss of data
halpecocotools/_mask.c(11077): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'npy_intp' to 'siz', possible loss of data
halpecocotools/_mask.c(11965): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'siz', possible loss of data
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\numpy\core\include -Icommon "-IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include" "-IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" /Tccommon/maskApi.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\common/maskApi.obj
maskApi.c
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\numpy\core\include -Icommon "-IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include" "-IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" /Tc../common/maskApi.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\../common/maskApi.obj
maskApi.c
c1: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: '../common/maskApi.c': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.39.33519\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2


MaskApi.c exists inside HalpeCOCOAPI-master\PythonAPI\common, but i think the compiler is not pointing correctly to it. I tried to set the path directly like:
# Define the absolute paths for the source files directly
maskApi_c_path = r'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\ALPHA\HalpeCOCOAPI-master\PythonAPI\common\maskApi.c'
mask_pyx_path = r'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\ALPHA\HalpeCOCOAPI-master\PythonAPI\halpecocotools\_mask.pyx'

# Define the absolute path for the 'common' include directory
common_include_dir = r'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\ALPHA\HalpeCOCOAPI-master\PythonAPI\common'

ext_modules = [
    Extension(
        'halpecocotools._mask',
        sources=[maskApi_c_path, mask_pyx_path],
        include_dirs=[np.get_include(), common_include_dir],
        extra_compile_args=[],
    )
]

but it doesnt fix it

Have you followed the instructions in https://github.com/HaoyiZhu/HalpeCOCOAPI/issues/1?
